# Succinct class for rotational transforms (reducing redundancy)

Tags: java

I wrote this Java class for doing rotational transforms about the x,y,z axes.

```java
public class Coord {
    private double x,y,z;
    public Coord(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public Coord M(Coord[] M) {
        return new Coord(
                x*M[0].x + y*M[0].y + z*M[0].z,
                x*M[1].x + y*M[1].y + z*M[1].z,
                x*M[2].x + y*M[2].y + z*M[2].z);
    }
    public Coord xR(double theta) {
        double s = Math.sin(theta);
        double c = Math.cos(theta);
        return M(new Coord[]{V(1,0,0), V(0,c,-s), V(0,s,c)});
    }
    public Coord yR(double theta) {
        double s = Math.sin(theta);
        double c = Math.cos(theta);
        return M(new Coord[]{V(c,0,s), V(0,1,0), V(-s,0,c)});
    }
    public Coord zR(double theta) {
        double s = Math.sin(theta);
        double c = Math.cos(theta);
        return M(new Coord[]{V(c,-s,0), V(s,c,0), V(0,0,1)});
    }
    public Coord V(double x, double y, double z) {
        return new Coord(x,y,z);
    }
}
```

It transforms a x,y,z coordinate, as given by the class Coord, to a new coord by the matrix multiplication M. It works OK, such as `Coord c = new Coord(1,1,0).xR(0.1);`, try `System.out.printf("%f,%f,%f", c.x, c.y, c.z);` will show a small rotation (theta=0.1 radians) about x, while keeping x constant.

Anyway, I want to know if there's any way of getting rid of all the Math.sin, Math.cos while still maintaining readability (preferably) - but just getting rid of them would be good!. They are annoying to look at, and, seem to be asking to be reduced somehow

Comment: This would probably be a good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these `sin`/`cos` parts, IMHO. At least, you already introduced these `s`/`c` variables, which already makes it more readable than inlining everything. But note that the *overall* structure is a bit unusual. Usually, one represents all this in a dedicated `Matrix` class which internally stores 9 (or 16) plain doubles, and thus, the way of calling/using such a class usually looks different. Something like http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix4f.html may not be the perfect example, but give an idea.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with what you've written. The best I can suggest is putting `import static java.lang.Math.sin; import static java.lang.Math.cos;` at the top. Then you can get away with `sin` and `cos` rather than `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`.

Comment: It somehow grates .. in some functional styles the operation could be passed into the matrix, but seems there is a dead end here in Java

Comment: Do I really have to keep on living with 6 lines of Math-theta, it's going to be a long night

Comment: You could introduce methods like `private static double c(double t) { return Math.cos(t); }` and then write `return M(new Coord[]{V(c(theta),-s(theta),0) ...`, but this would neither be more efficient nor more readable. Write the code as clearly as possible. (This also refers to methods which should not be called `xR`, but `rotateX` etc, but this only as a side note...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Paul's comment, turns out to be pretty good

```
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;

public class Coord {
    private double x,y,z;
    public Coord(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public Coord M(Coord[] M) {
        return new Coord(
                x*M[0].x + y*M[0].y + z*M[0].z,
                x*M[1].x + y*M[1].y + z*M[1].z,
                x*M[2].x + y*M[2].y + z*M[2].z);
    }
    public Coord xR(double t) {
        return M(new Coord[]{V(1,0,0), V(0,cos(t),-sin(t)), V(0,sin(t),cos(t))});
    }
    public Coord yR(double t) {
        return M(new Coord[]{V(cos(t),0,sin(t)), V(0,1,0), V(-sin(t),0,cos(t))});
    }
    public Coord zR(double t) {
        return M(new Coord[]{V(cos(t),-sin(t),0), V(sin(t),cos(t),0), V(0,0,1)});
    }
    public Coord V(double x, double y, double z) {
        return new Coord(x,y,z);
    }
}
```

Answering my own Q .. happy to know of other ways, looks pretty syntax bare now though .... I think I can live with this